# How to get postdata attached to http request using npapi plugin

Tags: c++, plugins, browser, network-programming, npapi

Is it possible to get postdata of post request using npapi plugin. We can easily access the url, cookies etc. using plugin, but what about post data!

```
FB::DOM::WindowPtr window = m_host->getDOMWindow();
referrer="";
title ="";postdata ="";
cookie = "";userAgent = "";

if (!window)
    return;

if (window->getJSObject()->HasProperty("document"))
     cookie = window->getNode("document")->getProperty<std::string>("cookie");
if (window->getJSObject()->HasProperty("document"))
     referrer = window->getNode("document")->getProperty<std::string>("referrer");
if (window->getJSObject()->HasProperty("document"))
     title = window->getNode("document")->getProperty<std::string>("title");
if (window->getJSObject()->HasProperty("navigator")) 
     userAgent = window->getNode("navigator")->getProperty<std::string>("userAgent");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you get it with Javascript? I don't think so; but if it were possible, that would be how you'd do it from NPAPI. NPAPI has no way to get the post data for a post request in a page, so the only stuff like that you can get is through javascript.

Comment: I don't know for sure either way, but it wouldn't surprise me in the slightest to learn that Chrome (or other browsers) keep some mimetypes reserved for themselves and don't let plugins override them.

Comment: The above method of retrieving cookies, doesn't return all the cookies. It skips the first cookie. Is it a bug which you can fix!